# Rails 4 save unusual model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get data from form, then process it in model, and after that save. I don't save data right from form.

I made a model like this:

```
class NewsParser < ActiveRecord::Base
def initialize a, h
   @queries = a
   @contents = h
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateNewsParsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :news_parsers do |t|
      t.text :contents
      t.text :queries
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And I want to save it to Database. So in controller I write:

```
class NewsParsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @news_parser = NewsParser.new([1,2,3], {1 => 3})
    @news_parser.save
  end
private
  def news_parser_params
    params.require(:news_parser).permit(:a, :h)
  end
end
```

It makes next error on the save line:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

How can I save my model?

Comment: Try giving like this `params.require(:my_model).permit(:a, :h)`

Comment: What is the name of the method which has this line `params.require(:my_model).permit(:queries, :contents)`?

Comment: Please post your full controller code

Comment: Where are your comments? Why you have removed them?

Comment: Please don't put the changes in the current code.It may confuse.

Comment: I change code to original.

Comment: Where is the code where you "process it" before saving? What is that doing to the data? There appears to be some major details missing from your question.

Comment: It will be in future. Now controller has only that lines, that I wrote. Except other methods, like show, index...

Answer (score 0):

As your method name is `news_parser_params`,i guess giving this line

```
@my_model = MyModel.new ([1,2,3], {1 => 3})
```

as

`@my_model = MyModel.new(news_parser_params)` should work!

**Update**

Now change this line back to the original

```
params.require(:my_model).permit(:a, :h)
```

to

```
params.require(:my_model).permit(:queries, :contents)
```

Comment: I wrote my way, because I want to get data from form, then process it in model, and after thar save. I don't save data right from form.

Comment: @Michael Ideally, you should still run your `params` through `require().permit()`.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't pass params to model at all. In future I will process them in controller and pass some other data to Model.

Answer (score 0):

In your `NewsParser` model add these two lines

```
serialize :queries, Array
serialize :contents, Hash
```

In your controller in `news_parser_params` method

```
params.require(:news_parser).permit(:contents => {}, :queries => [])
```

also here

```
@news_parser = NewsParser.new(:queries => [1,2,3], :contents => {1 => 3})
```

Comment: check my last line of code and tell me i its working or not, if not, what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The first thing, that I have done was to **remove** initialize method from model, as it was in first message.

```
class NewsParser < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize a, h
   @queries = a
   @contents = h
  end
end
```

Next. There is a quote in "The Rails 4 Way", that helped me to save attribute values.

> ...there is also a write_attribute method that lets you change attribute values.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The description for a project cannot be changed to a blank string
  def description=(new_value)
    write_attribute(:description, new_value) unless new_value.blank?
  end
end
```

So now it looks that way:

```
class NewsParser < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :queries, Array
  serialize :contents, Hash

  def add_query str
    @queries ||= []
    @queries << CGI.escape(str)
    write_attribute(:queries, @queries)
  end
end
```

And permits there don't need at all.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?